# Using AngularJS ngUpload to save image to CouchDB

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, couchdb

I'm looking at the AngularJS ngUpload module. I want to upload and save images to CouchDB. While the docs for ngUpload look pretty straightforward, I'm not sure how to get the uploaded `content` pushed to a CouchDB attachment. I do have CouchDB installed locally and I have an Angular factory saving documents fine. That part is all good. Can someone post an Angular controller (or a service/factory would be better) example that would write the uploaded image content to CouchDB attachment?

Thanks a lot for your help here :-)